# Build android webrtc on Android Studio failed

Tags: java, webrtc

I did following manual:
https://webrtc.org/native-code/android/
My main buid.gradle:

```
    buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.0-beta02"
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

And the error is:

```
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':build.android.buildhooks.build_hooks_android_java:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:103)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:73)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.execute(OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.java:51)
```

Comment: If you still need it, I have maintained a complete tutorial to solve all the issues. You can also visit this reference article: [Compile_WebRTC_Library_For_Android](https://github.com/mail2chromium/Compile_WebRTC_Library_For_Android)